# Exclude a category if post is only in that category using wp_Query

Tags: wp-query

I have two categories

- Category1 (ID = 1)
- Category2 (ID = 2)

I want to display posts Which are in Category2 and in (Category1 + Category2).

If a post is only in Category1 then it should not display.

I have used the following code.

```
'category__in'     => array(2)
```

It works but I think it is not the correct way. As if in the future if I add a new category then I will have to add its id here in the code to display the post which also in that new category.

Is there any proper way to exclude only Category1 posts if post in only in Category1?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is very unusual case, and the only solution I can think of here is to get an array of category ids to include into `category__in` in order to skip posts that are **only** assigned to category `1`

In order to achieve this, we must

- use [`get_terms()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms) to get all the categories. We will use the `exclude` parameter to exclude category `1` from that list. We will also set the `fields` parameter to `ids` in order to get an array of category ids
- pass the array from the result from `get_terms()` to `category__in`

Example

```
$cat_ids = get_terms( 'category', array( 'fields' => 'ids', 'exclude' => 1 ) );
```

and then use it as follow

```
'category__in' => $cat_ids,
```

Just a note, you would need to check if you actually have categories returned by `get_terms()` and that no error is returned before you run your query. You don't want to pass an empty array or error to `category__in`

### EDIT

I have scrapped the `get_categories` idea and went with `get_terms()` as `get_terms` is used by `get_categories` and we can also set `get_terms()` to only return the category ids, and that is exactly all that is needed.

The original post is updated to reflect the changes

Comment: If I add new category then I will also modify this code so that it also display posts within that new category.

Comment: How if I get all the categories ids dynamically and exclude that specific one and assign to the `category__in` property like this:
`$catids = get_category_ids_except_category1();
'category__in' => $catids`

Comment: I have scrapped the `get_categories` idea to go with `get_terms()` which is much better. Please feel free to check the updated post. :-)

Comment: Any feedback on this? :-)

Comment: I didn't try this But I think it will work.
I get all the cat ids using `get_all_category_ids()` and unset that category id from the returned array and then use `category__in => $cat_ids`.

Comment: No problem, take your time and test it thouroughly. Just curious if this approach is viable. :-)

Comment: Also, with the new approach I have posted last night, it will be faster than `get_all_category_ids()`

Answer (score 0):

I am only guessing, but sollution must be similar to

```
$args = array(
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => array(1, 2),
            'operator' => 'AND'
        )
    )
);
$results = new WP_Query( $args );
```