# Exclude posts that only have the 'Uncategorized' category

Tags: posts, wp-query, categories, taxonomy, terms

I want to exclude posts that *only* have the Uncategorized category (i.e. category id 1), but if a post is (erroneously) categorised as "Uncategorized" but also has other categories, I want to include it.

Every solution I've found so far excludes all posts with the Uncategorized category, whether they have other categories or not. I've tried:

```
'category__not_in' => array('1')
```

and

```
'cat' => -1
```

in the query arguments but I'm not getting the results I need. Is there a way around this?

Comment: [Found it](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/187443/31545) :-)

Comment: Thanks, upvoted there, but will also add my own answer as the final solution was subtly different.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Working off of Pieter Goosen's answer to [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/187443/exclude-a-category-if-post-is-only-in-that-category-using-wp-query), the way around this is to create a list of all the categories except the one you want to exclude, then search for posts that include them. That way, if a post has the excluded category but also other categories, it'll be included. So, in my case:

```
$args = array ('exclude'=>1,'fields'=>'ids');   
$exclude_uncategorized = get_terms('category',$args);
```

and then include the following in the `$args` for the `wp_query`:

```
'category__in' => $exclude_uncategorized,
```

Comment: I have looked through my and your approach, stupid me, forgot the taxonomy parameter in `get_terms`. Enjoy :-)